# Geocoder vs Geokit for finding objects within X miles of a latitude/longitude coordinate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, geokit

Newbie to Rails. I am building an app where users create events at a certain location, and plan to host on heroku. Other users can view events taking place within x miles of their latitude/longitude. I'm looking for a solution that would help me fetch all events happening in an x mile radius. The options seem to be [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and [Geokit](https://github.com/andre/geokit-rails). Geokit seems to be more popular but doesn't seem to be ready for Rails 3. Is there an obvious choice for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: There is a Rails3 branch of geokit (which I do use): https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), which is provided via a Heroku addon. With Mongo you then have access to spacial queries ("find me all the events within this circle"): http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Unfortunately if you try to use Postgres's geospacial indexing you will find that Heroku does not offer it by default.

Take a look at [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) which enables you to do ActiveRecord-style representations of your documents in Mongo, and is very easy to get going with.

Comment: I thought Heroku only provides Postgresql. So I would have to host mongo elsewhere?  Also, won't it work if with postgres if i just use the geocoder or geokit gem/plugin?

Comment: You just add it as an addon: http://addons.heroku.com/mongohq It _may_ work for a while with Postgres but you're going to end up with some horrendous queries running against your database, and if your idea is something that takes off you'll end up having to rewrite it to use spacial queries, meaning self-hosted postgres with PostGIS.

Comment: Is Postgres really that weak that I can't run queries fetching events in a certain location range? It says on the Mongoid site that before proceeding I should have good to advnaced knowledge of Ruby and thorough knowledge of MongoDB otherwise i'm gonna be in a "world of pain". How many simultaneous queries would postgres top out at, could you tell me? thx

Comment: hey stef, can you show a sample geospatial call in ruby to mongo?

Comment: John, which solution did you end up running with?